# Aplicación Java no redirecciona al hacer login tras migrar de tomcat a weblogic

Tags: java, java-ee, weblogic

Estoy migrando una aplicación Java de servidor que actualmente se encuentra montada sobre ***Apache Tomcat 7***, donde funciona perfectamente. La migración la estoy realizando a ***Weblogic 12c***

Tras instalar Weblogic e iniciarlo, he configurado los usuarios y grupos tanto en el servidor como en los ficheros ***weblogic.xml*** y ***web.xml*** de la aplicación. 
He desplegado la aplicación en el servidor y levanta bien, cargando la pantalla de login.

El problema surge en el momento en que hago login con el usuario y password, los reconoce, pero no redirecciona a la pantalla principal de la aplicación sino que vuelve a mostrar la pantalla de login.

Mirando los logs, lo único que me da una pista son los siguientes warnings:

> Recompiling JSP [ServletContext@1091500681[app:pwc_riesgos module:pwc_riesgos.war path:null spec-version:3.1]], resource [/index.jsp], because t is stale.
>
> For security constraint with url-pattern /jsp/* in web application pwc_riesgos.war, only the http methods "POST GET " are covered.
>
> For security constraint with url-pattern /login.html in web application pwc_riesgos.war, only the http methods "POST GET " are covered.
>
> For security constraint with url-pattern *.html in web application pwc_riesgos.war, only the http methods "POST GET " are covered.
>
> For security constraint with url-pattern /login.html in web application pwc_riesgos.war, only the http methods "POST GET " are covered.

El fichero **web.xml** de la app contiene lo siguiente:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>PoliticasSeguridad</web-resource-name>
           <description>
                Paginas accesibles para el login
           </description>
           <url-pattern>/login.html</url-pattern>
           <http-method>GET</http-method>
           <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>PoliticasSeguridad</web-resource-name>
           <description>
                Paginas solo accesibles con autorizacion
           </description>
           <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
           <url-pattern>/jsp/*</url-pattern>
           <http-method>GET</http-method>
           <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>Todos</role-name>
            <role-name>Administradores</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

He encontrado un enlace a una pregunta parecida al sitio en inglés, [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705846/security-constraint-url-pattern-and-the-character-within-web-xml), pero no consigo solucionar nada.

Comment: ¿Cuando dice que el servidor "reconoce el usuario y password"... a qué te refieres exactamente? Piensa que aquí no sabemos lo habituado que estás a configurar WL y no sabemos si el JAAS (suponiendo que sea JAAS) está bien configurado.

Comment: @SJuan76 me referia a que validaba bien el usuario y contraseña pero no era capaz de redirigir a la página principal. Lo he solucionado. Añado respuesta a la pregunta por si a alguien más le pasa. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución a mi problema está en que me faltaba de definir el usuario con el que intentaba conectarme dentro de los roles autorizados (`<auth-constraint>`) para acceder a las páginas definidas en `<security-constraint>`

Concretamente, para las URL definidas por los patrones siguientes:

```
<security-constraint>
    ...
           <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
           <url-pattern>/jsp/*</url-pattern>
           <http-method>GET</http-method>
           <http-method>POST</http-method>
    ...
</security-constraint>
```

Me faltaba añadir el usuario con el que me intentaba loguear: 
`<role-name>8492</role-name>`

Finalmente el código queda de la siguiente manera:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>PoliticasSeguridad</web-resource-name>
           <description>
                Paginas solo accesibles con autorizacion
           </description>
           <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
           <url-pattern>/jsp/*</url-pattern>
           <http-method>GET</http-method>
           <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>Todos</role-name>
            <role-name>Administradores</role-name>
            <role-name>8492</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```